# Ag-grid / Angular: How to make a double-click event on the column header before the sort event?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I'd like to double-click on a column header before sorting. I can't do this because the data is loaded after the first click on the header. I've tried setting a delay with jQuery before, but it doesn't work.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    ...
    (filterModified)="filterModified()"
    (sortChanged)="filterModified()"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```
OnInit(): void {
  const clickEvent = fromEvent<MouseEvent>($(this.element), "click");
  const dblClickEvent = fromEvent<MouseEvent>($(this.element), "dblclick");
  const eventsMerged = merge(clickEvent, dblClickEvent).pipe(debounceTime(50));
  
  eventsMerged.subscribe((e: Event) => {
    if (e.type === "dblclick") {
      console.log("dblclick");
    }
    if (e.type === "click") {
      console.log("click");
    }
  });
}

filterModified: void {

  setTimeout(() => {
     // loading data
  }, 300);
}
```

I don't know if what I've done is right. Can anyone help me?